# C Programme reading character by character into strings

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Basically what I'm doing is reading in a random text file, removing the punctuation and arranging the words into a linked list.

Everything works fine using this

```
printf("%c", (*(buf+x)));
```

so for example, the text file has the following

> "they're their where ever we may go go,"

the correct out put is printed

```
theyre
their
where
ever
we
may
go
go
```

My problem is, how do I convert these into strings and store them in an array?

Comment: PLease show all relevant code.

Comment: What is `buf` if it's not an array?

Comment: Apologies guys, the buf is a buffer which has dynamic memory allocated to it depending on the input file, the x is a counter counting each character each time my while loop is done. The reason why I haven't shown all my code is due to it being an assignment and the chances of it being plagarised.

Comment: Why would your code be plagiarized if doesn't do want you want?

Comment: Fair point, but it works fine up until this point, I don't want my work to be flagged that it's somewhere online and then land into some trouble and be accused of plagiarism. It's a weird system they have in plpace

Comment: Why don't you do your own work? Won't that be better for you?

Comment: I have done my own work. Hence why I do not wish to put it up online as I do not want it to flag up as being plagarised by being found on the internet? My question used the term how, I was simply asking for advice not someone to give me code that I can copy. Nevertheless I have made it work, everyone has to start somewhere don't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to reuse `buf`, so you want to copy the words into separately allocated storage.  If you terminate each word in `buf` with a null byte prior to copying it, i.e. `'\0'`, then you can use `strdup` to copy it.  You can later free the space with `free`.  Add the following includes (the second is for `free`):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Here's a simple example:

```
buf[0] = 'a';
buf[1] = 'b';
buf[2] = 'c';
buf[3] = '\0';

str = strdup(buf);
```

Comment: So say I use the word "the" and the printf statement runs three times before it exits a while loop due to reaching a space. Do I then add the null terminator and then pass it on to str?

Comment: Right, once all the characters are in `buf`, add a `\0` byte to the end, then you can call `strdup`.  After that you can reuse `buf` for the next string.

Comment: Ok, I rephrased it and also added an example.

Comment: Bumped into a problem where it just prints the whole buffer

Comment: You need to save each string you create with `strdup`.  And when you begin each new word, you need to start at the beginning of `buf` (or, alternatively, add an offset to `buf` when you pass it to `strdup`).

Comment: Nope it's not worked unfortunately, as when I do that the punctuation is included

Comment: So, how would you solve that?  How about not putting the punctuation in `buf`?  Or, you could overwrite it after it's there.  One way or another, you need to remove it.  It would probably help if you tried to understand what the code is doing rather than just looking for a cookie-cutter solution that you don't really understand.  That way you can make it do exactly what you want.

Comment: I've solved the punctuation bit, all I want to do is now convert this characters into string. I understand what strdup and have had it working I'm fairly new to c and just getting used to coding in general so do I apologise if I come across as looking for a solution on here. All I'm looking for is for some advice the direction I need to go for, but I do thank you for making an effort in helping me. Guess I need to read up a bit more.

Comment: Ok, fair enough :)  Just remember what it's doing:  If you pass `buf` to `strdup`, it will simply copy the characters from `buf`, up to and including the terminating null byte, into a new dynamically allocated string.  And it returns that new string.  So whatever is in `buf` at the time you call `strdup`, that's what you'll get.

Comment: Done it! Was really simple in the end as I used the sprintf function. Now can implement the above function and have it nearly all done!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to store the words from the file in an array and print them.
you can try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *buf[40];
    for (int n = 0; n < 40; n++)
    {
        buf[n] = (char*)malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
    }
    FILE *file;
    fopen_s(&file, "file.txt", "r");
    int c, i = 0, j = 0;
    bool init = 0;
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c != ' ')
        {
            buf[i][j] = c;
            j++;
            init = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (init)
            {
                buf[i][j] = '\0';
                i++;
                j = 0, init = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    buf[i][j] = '\0';
    for (int x = 0; x <= i; x++)
    {
        printf("word[%d] : %s\n", x, buf[x]);
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
    {
        free(buf[x]);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- **Try this code to understand better concept :**

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int main(void)
  {
  char c;
  int i = 0, count = 0,max = 0;
  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen("file.txt", "r");

     if(fp == 0)
     {
      printf("File is not opened\n");
     return;
     }
     else
      {
      //  Finding line having maximum characters from the file to allocate that  much memory..
         while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
         {
            count++;
             if(c == '\n')
              {
                  if(count > max)
                  max = count;
                  count = 0;
               }
               else
              { 
               count = 0;
              }

          }
      }
      rewind(fp);

   // Allocating the memory up to max line from the file.
      char *temp = (char*)malloc(max * sizeof(char)); 

        while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
        {  
           if ((c >= 'a' && c<='z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'z'))
            {
              temp[i++] = c;
            }
            else if(c == ' ' || c == '\n')
            {
              temp[i] = '\0';
              printf("%s\n",temp);
              i = 0;
              memset(temp,'\0',max);
             }
        }
  free(temp);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: Just been looking through it and its made a lot of sense, now that I'm using a linked list I'm guessing you add a pointer statement after printf, much simpler to how I have done it, thank you for helping me understand.